# How much JVM memory java heap space does the ExtJS Application uses

Tags: javascript, extjs, jboss, jvm, heap-memory

I would like to know how much of the JMV min memory and max memory (java heap space) that i need to set for the ExtJS application to perform well on my production server which is JBOSS server.

Is there a configuration file that is created after i build the application where i can set min, max memory of JVM to be used.

Can i test how much memory does ExtJS application uses.

Can i dictate server to use (i.e. with help of some configuration file) or allot a specific amount of JVM memory for my ExtJS Application.

I would like to know it so that i can set the min, max JVM options on my production server.

There is configuration file that talks about the JVM memory, but it is the memory that is being used when we build the application. The link that talks about it is
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/command_advanced

Any kind of help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: ExtJS is a JavaScript GUI Framework which runs on the clients and not the server side. Your question makes no sense

Comment: @sra Thanks, if you can put it in answers i will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS is a JavaScript GUI Framework which runs on the clients and not the server side.